# How can i send multiple items through buy now button of Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I desperately need some help, I cannot find the answer anywhere.
What I need to build is a "buy now" form (or button) where it send multiple items. I am selling tickets for an event, which has different prices for Adult and Child tickets. I have already used the "Add to cart" buttons individually, but my older customers are stuggling with this, especially mobile users. Also, this is really not the most professional way of doing it in my case. 
Just as an example, here is a form which is similar to what I need: http://lowfestival.es/abonos/ (I know this is not a paypal form, nor the same, but im sure you understand.
I just need 2 items (Adult and Child) with 2 quantity boxes and the Pay Now button.
If this is not possible for some reason, can anyone recommend a free 3rd party cart which could do the job?
Many many many thanks in advance for any help.
Kindest Regards

Answer (score 2):

The Cart Upload command will do this for you: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/

For example:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremailaddress@yourdomain.com">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="First item name">
<!-- Change this to the price of the first item -->
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15.00">
Quantity of first item:
<input type="number" name="quantity_1" size="2" min="1" max="99" required="required"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Second item name">
<!-- Change this to the price of the second item -->
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="20.00">
Quantity of second item:
<input type="number" name="quantity_2" size="2" min="1" max="99" required="required"><br>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/btn/btn_buynow_cc_171x47.png">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@mail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="beach ball">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="42">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="towel">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="13">

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It may be a great answer but without details and an explanation it may just not be useful to people. Please try including details